Synchronization bug in Pycharm
I am trying to debug my script in Pycharm, i am connected with remote ssh to an EC2 instance. When i created the my Pycharm Project i defined my ssh interpreter and defined the deployment as follows:

FAM is the name of my Project.
I am trying to debug one of the scripts (test_main.py) in the following filedir structure:

I placed the breakpoint on one of the line, when i press debug, a different script from ~/.cache dir is opened, it seems from some reason it opens the file in a cache dir.
I tried to invalidate the cache and also delete the ./cache dir manually, when i did it, when debugging the same row i get the error:


got a question? The second image of file structure you are showing is local path file structure, and mapping error is showing utils.py doesn't exist in remote path/ deployment path, can you check if utils.py exist on remote server.
